# I need to design multiple stores in same domain

Tags: multistore, localisation, multidomain

I am selling my products in three different countries so I need three different stores with different languages

Answer (score 0):

Follow This Link to setup multiple store:

http://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-in-magento2/